# Sending the line that failed regex as part of action in fail2ban?

Tags: fail2ban

With fail2ban, is it possible from the action to have handy the actual line that triggered the ban so that it could be included in the notification?

I haven't been able to find out how to do this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The  helper variable seems to be available for this purpose in the definition of an action (like ).